# Restrict Yammer Embed

Tags: yammer

I have been reading through the Yammer embed API doc and one thing to me is unclear. Can our users embed our Yammer group feeds into a website that will be publicly viewable?

I used the code that was provided by clicking on the Yammer Embed button from the web interface, and it appeared that it required authentication. Is it possible that a user could embed this in a website with an auth token so that it would be visible without login?

If this is possible, is there a way that I as a network admin can restrict the embed feature?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By the nature of Yammer being a private, corporate social network, you are NOT able to embed a feed from your network that is displayed publicly without user authentication using the Yammer Embed widget.

Comment: Thanks Chris! That's the answer I was expecting but it's good to hear it confirmed.